# How to compare running time between sorting methods quicksort and mergesort properly?

Tags: java

I have an assignment to compare the execution times for sorting large arrays of integers with mergesort and quicksort. The implementations of the algorithms are copied from a book. They both sort integers in ascending order. I am then asked to state how much faster quicksort is on average. However, with my (albeit small) sample size of tests, I found that mergesort was quicker by a small %, which leads me to believe i'm testing improperly.

I have 2 programs, one for mergesort and one for quicksort. Their main() code is the same (shown below). I create an array of random size between 0 and some chosen upper limit. Then I fill the array with random integers. Then I sort the array and print it. I use the currentTimeMillis() to check the runtime of the programs. I do tests of 10 runs for quicksort and mergesort, add the total time and divide by 10 to get the average running time for the sorts. I did not find that quicksort was faster than mergesort on average. I've also tried using a fixed array size, but the results still do not hint at quicksort being faster. What would be a -proper- way to test?

```
public static void main(String[] args){
        /* create an array of some size 0 to 100000 with
           random integers and measure the time it takes
           to sort the array in ascending order (where sort() is either quicksort 
           or mergesort.)
        */
        long a = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Random rnd = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
        Integer[] array = new Integer[rnd.nextInt(100000)];
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
            array[i] = rnd.nextInt();
        }
        sort(array);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
        long b = System.currentTimeMillis() - a;
        System.out.println("Program runtime: " + b + "ms");
    }
}

Expected result: Quicksort average running time should be some % faster
in comparison to mergesort, for large random integer arrays.

Actual result: Mergesort was slightly faster in most tests 
(10K elements, 100K elements, 1000K elements).
```

Comment: while picking random elements is fine, I wouldn't say so about picking random sizes for arrays

Comment: Show us your code where you implemented both sorting algorithms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your measurements include the generation of the random arrays, that's a heavy operation and will distort the result.

```java
// do initialization here

long a = System.nanoTime();
sort(array);
long b = System.nanoTime();

// do the output here
```

... will only measure the time that passed during the execution of `sort(array)`. Which is the time you are interested in.

Replacing `System.currentTimeMillis()` with `System.nanoTime()` makes the result more accurate.

Comment: Along with mangusta's answer of not picking random sizes of arrays, and excluding the array generation as part of the timing, I seem to be getting significant results now, where quicksort does indeed run faster. It turned out that array generation stood for more than 80% of the program runtime.